# Controller class extend not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php, controllers

I am working with Magento CE 1.9.0.1 and I like to extend the second controller from the first controller class.

**First controller**

```
class Federallawyer_Flphotos_SuggestController
    extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action { 
}
```

**Second controller**

```
class Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController
    extends Federallawyer_Flphotos_SuggestController {
}
```

the second controller is extended from the first controller, but Magento is throwing an error.

**the error is**

> Call to undefined method Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController::getCustomerSession(),

While I define this method in first controller file.

Any idea's or suggestions will help me

Answer (score 5):

This will not work without an `require()`:

```
<?php

require(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Federallawyer_Flphotos').DS.'SuggestController.php');

class Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController extends Federallawyer_Flphotos_SuggestController
{
//...
}
```

Controller actions will resolve the main controller class (`Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController`) based on configuration and routing, but it is extending another class (`Federallawyer_Flphotos_SuggestController`) which PHP has to resolve on its own using the autoloading conventions.

Comment: i follow your way but still throw an error.Fatal error: Class 'Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController' not found in /home/vhosts/FederalLawyer/app/code/local/Federallawyer/Flphotos/controllers/SuggestController.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

try adding following code in your second controller class

```
require_once 'Federallawyer/Flphotos/controllers/SuggestController.php';
class Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController extends Federallawyer_Flphotos_SuggestController {
}
```

Comment: i follow your way but still throw an error.Fatal error: Class 'Federallawyer_Flphotos_ConnectController' not found in /home/vhosts/FederalLawyer/app/code/local/Federallawyer/Flphotos/controllers/SuggestController.php on line 2